# Separate int and char and making whole number

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple program that split a string in the argument into number, letter and operators, however I come across that **23x+3=8**

```
foreach (char x in args[i]){

    if (char.IsNumber(x)){
        inter[i] = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a number ", x);
    }
    else if (char.IsLetter(x)){
        apha[i] = x;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Letter ", x);
    }
    else if (char.IsSymbol(x)){
        symbol[i] = x;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Symbol ", x);
    }
```

I found the output is separate into each char 2 and 3  I want to have 23 as a whole number. Is there way to push 2 number together?

Comment: Try using *String.Split* instead of looping.

Comment: You want to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)  your string into a) digits, b) operators and c) whitespace.  That means you need to 1) evaluate the string a character at a time, 2) group digits together as you go alone and 3) keep running list of each number (operand) and it's corresponding operator.  You also need to decide if you want to handle "complexities" like parenthesis or operator precedence.  For example, how would you evaluate `2+3*4`?  Would it be "20"?  Or "14"?

Comment: Google "c# lexer" for basic hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following

```
string equation = "25x+20=120";

// Guard against an empty input
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equation))
    throw new ArgumentException("No equation given!");

// Regex split
// Split is being applied on the mathematical operations
var result = Regex.Split(equation, @"([*+-/=])");
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    // TODO : Further operations
}
```

This will generate the output

```
25x
+
20
=
120
```

The process uses regular expressions.  The `([*+-/=])` will split on the specified mathematical operations, the `()` will ensure the operation is included in the resultant split and thus allow you to rebuild the operation tree.

See the docs at [System.Text.RegularExpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2), and you can see a more in depth reference at [Regular Expression Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you have to rewrite your algorithm. I'd probably enumerate chars just like you and accumulate them in a `StringBuilder` until end of the line or until the type changes e.g. number changes to a variable or symbol. Once it happens, do what you need to do with your accumulated data and restart the accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below code, it uses regular expressions, which make the task very easy:

```
  string equation = "25x+20=120";
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(equation))
    throw new ArgumentException("No equation given!");
  //match all numbers
  var numbers = Regex.Matches(equation, @"\d+");
  //match all symbols
  var letters = Regex.Matches(equation, @"[a-zA-Z]");
  //take out all digits and letters, so only symbosl are left
  var symbols = Regex.Replace(equation, @"[0-9a-zA-Z]", "");
  //alternative:
  //var symbols = Regex.Matches(equation, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]");
  foreach(Match number in numbers)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Number ", number.ToString());
  }
  foreach (Match letter in letters)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Letter ", letter.ToString());
  }
  //alternative
  //foreach (Match symbol in symbols)
  foreach (char symbol in symbols)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Symbol ", symbol.ToString());
  }
```

It produces following output:

```
25 is a Number 
20 is a Number 
120 is a Number 
x is a Letter 
+ is a Symbol 
= is a Symbol
```

To list all parts in order, try this code:

```
  string equation = "25x+20=120";
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(equation))
    throw new ArgumentException("No equation given!");
  //match all numbers
  var numbers = Regex.Matches(equation, @"\d+");
  //match all symbols
  var letters = Regex.Matches(equation, @"[a-zA-Z]");
  //take out all digits and letters, so only symbosl are left
  var symbols = Regex.Matches(equation, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]");

  List<Tuple<int, string, string>> parts = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();

  foreach (Match number in numbers)
    parts.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string>(number.Index, number.ToString(), "Number"));
  foreach (Match letter in letters)
    parts.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string>(letter.Index, letter.ToString(), "Letter"));
  foreach (Match symbol in symbols)
    parts.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string>(symbol.Index, symbol.ToString(), "Symbol"));

  foreach(var part in parts.OrderBy(t => t.Item1))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a {1}", part.Item2, part.Item3);
```

Comment: One problem with this is that you now don't know that that X belongs to that 25

Comment: @HansKeﬆing What do you mean? OP clearly wants to distinct between numbers and letters.. so how 25x can be a number/letter? What would it be?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the expression (which I am guessing at is what the OP eventually wants), you not only need the parts, but also their relations/order

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Well, you might be right. See updated version.